# Jmeter View Results Tree displays incorrect amount of threads.

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

My **Thread Group** contains 10 threads with 20 ramp up period. Inside it there 2 samplers called **HTTP Requests** (one for login, other for getting form) and listener called **View Results Tree**. Once run, listener only displays three threads under each http request. The question is how to configure it in order to display all of the run threads?

Comment: View results tree doesn't display threads UNDER each HTTP request. If you see something under HTTP request, it must be a redirect (i.e. if HTTP request follows redirects). Threads are displayed on top level, so for 10 threads x 1 iteration x 2 requests, you should see 20 items on top level. But it also depends on other things. For example, if you included "successes only", then failing requests won't be displayed.

Comment: @KirilS. Well, why **View ResultsTree** always  displays 3 thread results under each HTTP Request once I expand it? Even if I change the number of threads to 1, still Tree Results shows 3?

Comment: @GordonFreaman: Because you are using `Follow Redirects` option checked in the HTTP Sampler level, which is default checked.
As per JMeter documentation Follow Redirects: This only has any effect if "Redirect Automatically" is not enabled.
        If set, the JMeter sampler will check if the response is a redirect and follow it if so.
        The initial redirect and further responses will appear as additional samples.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View Results Tree doesn't display "threads", it displays HTTTP Requests and associated **sample result(s)**. There might be some cases when single requests results in multiple nested requests, i.e.

- [URL Redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection)
- Embedded Resources (images, scripts, styles)

So for instance if you run 1 request to some site with 1 user and it results in 3 sample results it may be due to:

1. Response to the main request
2. Redirect somewhere else
3. Downloading associated image

[image: JMeter Redirect and Download embedded resoures]

Theoretically you can configure JMeter for not following redirects and not downloading embedded resources, but this way your test won't be realistic and most probably it is not something you would like to achieve.

---

Don't forget to disable or delete View Results Tree listener from your test plan when it comes to real load test as it may be **very** memory intensive so your it will impact your results in a negative way. See [Greedy Listeners - Memory Leeches of Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) article for more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot.